# C++ Program not reading formulas

Tags: c++, math, loops, numbers

**My program I have been working on is supposed to output the following:
* The number of gallons of paint required
* The hours of labor required
* The cost of the paint
* The labor charges
* The total cost of the paint job
However, it displays 0 in every field.. What have I done wrong now?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.**

Here is my code:

```
//Headers
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void PaintJobEstimator(double gallonprice, double calc)
{
    float numBucket=0;
    float hours=0;
    float bucketCost=0;
    float laborCharges=0;
    float totalCost=0;
    //calculates number of buckets of paint (gallons) needed
    numBucket=numBucket+calc*(1/115);
    //calculates paint cost
    bucketCost=bucketCost+gallonprice*numBucket;
    //calculates labor hour
    hours=hours+calc*(8/115);
    //calculates labor charges
    laborCharges=hours*18;
    //calculates total cost
    totalCost=totalCost+bucketCost+laborCharges;
    //Console output
    cout << "The number of Gallons of paint required:\t" << setprecision(2) << numBucket << endl;
    cout << "The hours of labor required:\t" << setprecision(2) << hours << " hrs" << endl;
    cout << "The labor charges:\t$" << setprecision(2) << laborCharges << endl;
    cout << "The cost of the paint:\t$" << setprecision(2) << bucketCost << endl;
    cout << "The total cost of the paint job:\t$" << setprecision(2) << totalCost << endl;
}

void main ()
{
    int rooms;
    double calc=0;
    double wallspace;
    double gallonprice;
    cout << "=========================================================\n";
    cout << "___________________Paint Job Estimator___________________\n";
    cout << "_________________________________________________________\n";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of rooms: ";
    cin >> rooms;
    while (rooms<1) //validates rooms
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry, enter one or more rooms:\t";
        cin >> rooms;
    }
    for (int roomNum=1;
        roomNum<=rooms;
        roomNum++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the wall space in square meters for room " << roomNum << ":\t" << endl;
        cin >> wallspace;
        while (wallspace < 0.01)//validates wallspace
        {
            cout << "Invalid entry, please re-enter the wall area for room " << roomNum << ":\t";
            cin >> wallspace;
        }
        calc=calc+wallspace;
    }//end loop
    cout << "\nEnter price of the paint per gallon: ";
    cin >> gallonprice;
    if (gallonprice <10) //validates price per gallon
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry, Reenter price at a $10.00 minimum: ";
        cin >> gallonprice;
    }
    PaintJobEstimator(gallonprice,wallspace);
    system ("pause");
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the console:[image]

Comment: `paint.cc:34:12: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're multiplying by zero in some of the calculations. For example, in the following line of code:

```
numBucket=numBucket+calc*(1/115);
```

You put 1/115 in parenthesis, which evaluates to zero because of integer division. To achieve the desired effect, try:

```
numBucket = calc / 115.0f;
```